# Why is recursion not working as expected in C

Tags: c, recursion, gcc

I want to count numbers in int from user input from char to zero. This code make only 1 cycle. (Please help me understand what is wrong in second part.)

```
void count_down_from(int num);
int main()
{
    int start;
    char letter;
    printf("print letter to reduce to zero in ACSCII");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
 
    count_down_from(letter);
    return 0;
}
```

This part working not good:

```
 void count_down_from(int num)
    {
        if (num > 0)
        {
            --num;
            count_down_from;
            printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    }
```

What behaviour expected:

```
void count_down_from(int num)
{
    printf("%d\n", num);
    --num;
    if (num < 0)
        return;
    else
        count_down_from(num);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual behaviour vs actual behaviour is. Can you please give the exact input, expected output and actual output? And why do you show two versions of the code? Are you saying one works but one doesn't?

Comment: Exactly. Second block working not fine. 3d code works like the second must.

Comment: The statement `count_down_from;` does absolutely nothing, and if your compiler doesn't warn you of that you haven't raised your warning levels enough. You have a function that works (the last code block), and a function that doesn't (the second code block). The differences of the two are *exactly* the reasons for that. So, I don't see what the question here even is.

Comment: What you mean "does absolutely nothing"? My compiler gcc latest version. Whats wrong with code?

Comment: `count_down_from` is a function. So just `count_down_from;` is not valid function call syntax and does essentially nothing. To call a function you need to do `count_down_from(num);`. You should be able to see that even by just comparing with the second code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at my modifications

```
void count_down_from(int num)
    {
        if (num >= 0) //need the >= operator to go down to zero not just 1
        {

            printf("%d\n", num);
            --num;
            count_down_from(num); //you need to send num to the call otherwise it won't be a recursive function
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

Comment: The `else return;` is a bit pointless; the code will return anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Missed (num) in function call in second block.